# Position management and market-making techniques

Tags: market-making, market-microstructure, position-sizing

Suppose, there is a HF strategy (agent) that is based on order book microstructure, and it is able to make good executions locally. More formally, in average its execution price is better than asset price $\tau$ sec. after the execution. Suppose, we manage two such agents: one for long orders, another for short orders.

The question is how to develop a controller that synchronizes between two and manages their mutual position given position limit `N` on each side, and maximal order size `n`.

I assume, this is a very broadly studied problem, especially among market makers. Can you please recommend relevant articles and ideas that provide overview of this topic and most sophisticated approaches. I'm especially interested in the very details such as: 1) Timing. is it prudent to generate random time intervals between last execution and new orders placement? 2) Pricing. How many orders can be executed on the same price? Thank you.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This paper [Dealing with the Inventory Risk. A solution to the market making problem](http://arxiv.org/abs/1105.3115), has a full bibliography and explains the intra day market making mechanism.

The model is made of two components:

- a diffusion of the *fair price* (to model the market risk)
- a point process (with an intensity in $A \exp -k \delta$ (where $\delta$ is the distance to the fair price) to model the probability to be hit once you choose  quote price

Then a stochastic control framework is set up to continuously adjust the quotes: distances (bid / ask) to the faire price.

Thanks to a tricky change of variable, the problem is solved.

Comment: I like the referenced paper thus far, still need to dig a bit deeper as it seems to make a lot of assumptions re price dynamics and arrival times. You may want to point out that this is partly your paper unless the name of one of the authors is coincidental. But nonetheless +1.

Comment: yes I am one of the authors of the paper, @Freddy, the assumptions we made are realistic in the sense that when the market is not "stressed", they are reasonable.  When the market is stressed, no model will work...

Comment: @lehalle, thanks for the disclaimer. Regarding your statement that no models work in stressed markets, I beg to disagree. You would essentially disqualify jump models with your statements. Discontinuous jumps are clearly a situation in which some external "stress" factor induced prices to discontinuously jump 20%, for example. Or to stick to this particular area, in many markets a stock can suddenly stop trading due to pending announcements or external events which generally precludes a larger jump, even when considering intraday hft markets.

Comment: @lehalle, one remark. I understand that you didn't put much effort for simulation, but this assumption is way too optimistic: "we assumed that our orders were entirely ﬁlled when a trade occurred at or above the ask price quoted by the agent".

Comment: @lehalle, did you test this model in the ideal setup, i.e. where price, time, and trades process are continuous and behave exactly as the model assumes? Would it generate any non-zero p&l? If not, why would it became profitable when used in discrete world?

Comment: @Serg: this assumption is commonly used, to avoid it, you should have a "passive market impact model". Nobody have one. The only other possible viewpoint (according to me at least), is to be 100% non parametric. I develop such a viewpoint in "Optimal posting price of limit orders: learning by trading" with S Laruelle et G Pagès ( http://arxiv.org/abs/1112.2397 ). Very good question about testing the optimal policy against the 'theoretical model', it is the usual first step and we implemented it. It works as soon as the volatility is not too high (as expected).

Comment: @Freddy of course you are right. The fact is that market making loose money in case of unexpected jump. Of course in the model of the paper you can obtain some robustness to jump (if you compensate it on the intensity of the flow). But you will post quotes very far away from the mid point, thus beging out of the market more often.

Comment: it for sure involves making compromises. Hey, I like your paper, I read through it. The math was developed quite neatly, though I still believe (as earlier pointed out) that you make a lot of simplifying assumptions, especially in your back test. You could at least have incorporated true bid-ask spreads and simulated inventory in a bit smarter way. But again the math in your paper I learned quite a few bits and pieces.

Comment: I agree with Freddy. The math is strong, but not simulation. Using raw exchange data it's possible to simulate limit orders execution with very high precision. It requires implementation of instrument-specific matching algorithm like FIFO or Pro-Rata. The only assumption needed is that each order size is negligible, and there is no long term impact on price, i.e. low volume participation.

Comment: @lehalle What is the relationship between market data and the assignment of variables A, k, & σ. Please excuse my ignorance.

Answer (score 3):

You first need to clearly define your constraints first:

- max single position size
- max net exposure

I am not sure why you want to limit order size. The whole idea of hft strategies is to maximize turnover. As long as your strategy generates alpha you should allow it to trade as often as the strategy prescribes. All you need to then do is to constrain the strategy and OMS to adhere to your position and exposure limits.

Comment: Yes, in general, the max. order size can be twice the max. exposure. I can of course let both sides to trade freely just withing exposure limits, but there might be better techniques, such as answered by Lehalle.